# WebSphereApplication NoClassDefFoundError while unmarshalling XML with JAXB

Tags: jaxb, websphere

I´ve deployed an EAR on a Websphere Application Server 7. In my code there is a part where I try to unmarshall a XML file into an object. I get this error when trying to do that:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.xtq.bcel.util.SyntheticRepository (initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
at com.ibm.xtq.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.<init>(JavaClass.java:109)
at com.ibm.xtq.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.<init>(JavaClass.java:228)
at com.ibm.xtq.bcel.generic.ClassGen.getJavaClass(ClassGen.java:174)
at com.ibm.fcg.bcel.FcgClassGenBCEL.dump2(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.fcg.bcel.FcgClassGenBCEL.dump(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.codegen.fcg.FCGDeserializationStubGenerator.generate(FCGDeserializationStubGenerator.java:249)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.codegen.AbstractGeneratedStubFactory.generateByteCode(AbstractGeneratedStubFactory.java:96)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.codegen.fcg.FCGStubFactory.generateStubByteCode(FCGStubFactory.java:46)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.codegen.AbstractGeneratedStubFactory.getStubClassConstructor(AbstractGeneratedStubFactory.java:154)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.codegen.AbstractGeneratedDeserializationStubFactory.createStub(AbstractGeneratedDeserializationStubFactory.java:58)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.DeserializationContext.startComplexType(DeserializationContext.java:662)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.DeserializationContext.handleRootElementEvent(DeserializationContext.java:303)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.produceRootElementEvent(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:186)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.scanRootElement(DocumentScanner.java:2234)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.scanProlog(DocumentScanner.java:1726)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.nextEvent(DocumentScanner.java:1316)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.parseDocumentEntity(DocumentScanner.java:1168)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.unmarshal(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:125)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:120)
at com.inditex.lois.core.ws.utilidades.services.impl.AdaptadorServiceImpl.transformarXMLenObjeto(AdaptadorServiceImpl.java:137)
```

As far as I know that class is part of IBM JDK and cannot be found in runtime. Is there anything I have to modify in my ear or, as I guess, its all about configuring/modifiying WAS configuration (or even applying a patch if this is a bug).

Any help? Thanks a lot.

(Sorry for my english :) )

Comment: Hi, do you also have a ClassNotFoundException in the stack trace? Or it's just the ClassDefNotFoundException? Could you post the full Stack Trace? Does the log shows if it was generated an FFDC log file for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here, there is an APAR:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV41639

```
Problem conclusion
This defect will be fixed in:
6.0.0 SR14
6.0.1 SR6
7.0.0 SR5
.
The fix resolved the AccessControlException. SyntheticRepository
class can be initialized properly, hence NoClassDefFoundError
does not occur.
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception means that the class `com.ibm.xtq.bcel.util.SyntheticRepository` is found, but failed static initialization. If there is no other message in the log about this, then this is the time to open a PMR with IBM. Static initializers in internal WebSphere code should never fail during normal usage course.